# Xcode crashes with exit code 11 when downgrading from Xcode 7 to 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have upgraded Xcode 7 Beta and deleted both of Xcode 6 and 7. After days, I have downloaded Xcode 6.4 from App Store.

I compile my project, I saw the following compile error.

```
Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 11
```

How Can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Xcode 6 beta. If you use GitHub then you can check for changes within the project e.g storyboards and plists.

Quite often when opening a project with a newer version of Xcode, it will be upgraded for the new version of Xcode, these changes are not always backwards compatible.